# Using nginx server as proxy along glassfish server for static content loading

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, nginx, glassfish

Have been working on a java-ee restful application, and the  front end is based on react.js. So i was looking for a good way to load static content and some file uploads to be handle by an nginx server. Have heard nginx is good for static file content loading, though am new to the nginx server environment so is are there use case or what is the best practices of using the nginx server along a glassfish sever.

Answer (score 2):

You are heading in the right direction - you could use a webserver, e.g. nginx for serving static content, like files or static parts of your web content. And you should use it in a productive environment anyway, for several reaons.

First, if you have reasonable traffic, this shifts part of the load to another machine (as long as you have several machines at hand). This is not only good for big static content, e.g. serving files, but also for the many small parts. Consider for example having an image in a CSS class pointing to a resource within your deployed application to style a button, then your GlassFish will have to serve it along with your other dynamic web content. If on the other hand, it will come from an URL, it can be handled by your webserver and due to the static URL it can also be cached and directly used from there without serving it over and over again.

And then, apart from performance, your webserver will allow for handling security issues before the request reaches your application server. So you can for example decide based on the URL of your REST services which node should handle it and which security guidelines to follow, for example if an SSL certificate must be provided.

But all in all, it depends very much on your application and environment. It might not be necessary at all to build all this if it's OK for your purposes to let the GlassFish handle everything.